# Panel data: mean, groupby and with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate first the mean of jobs whenever `entr ==1` and second the mean of `jobs` by `year_of_life`.

```
id  year  entry  cohort  jobs  year_of_life
1  2009    0     NaN      10      NaN
1  2012    1     2012     12      0
1  2013    0     2012     12      1
1  2014    0     2012     13      2
2  2010    1     2010     2       0
2  2011    0     2010     3       1
2  2012    0     2010     3       2
3  2007    0     NaN      4       Nan
3  2008    0     NaN      4       Nan
3  2012    1     2012     5       0
3  2013    0     2012     5       1
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your first requirement -

```
df.query('entry == 1').jobs.mean()
6.333333333333333
```

---

Addressing your second requirement - here, I consider only jobs where `entry` is `1`.

```
df.assign(jobs=df.jobs.mask(df.entry == 1)).groupby('year_of_life').jobs.mean()

year_of_life
0           NaN
1      6.666667
2      8.000000
Nan    4.000000
Name: jobs, dtype: float64
```

If you just want mean by `year_of_life`, a simple groupby will suffice.

```
df.groupby('year_of_life').jobs.mean()

year_of_life
0      6.333333
1      6.666667
2      8.000000
Nan    4.000000
Name: jobs, dtype: float64
```

---

Note that this is different from what the other answer is suggesting, which I think isn't what you're looking for:

```
df.query('entry == 1').groupby('year_of_life').jobs.mean()

year_of_life
0    6.333333
Name: jobs, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first you can use boolean indexing to filter the dataframe for rows where the condition is True then take the mean `df[df.entry == 1].mean()`. For the second, groupby year_of_life then take the mean of each group `df.groupby('year_of_life').mean()`. If you want both of the condition to be satisfied then do the grouping try `df[df.entry == 1].groupby('year_of_life').mean()`.